# Infinite loop of BN_mod_sqrt not resolved after updating openssl in Ubuntu

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-18.04, cve

as I mentioned; I updated my openssl version to 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.15 and followed the code mentioned in github.com/drago-96/CVE-2022-0778 to verify if it is fixed. But it's going into an infinite loop. Do I need to update any other package? Or not linking something properly?

Edit: could verify the fix after I did "apt upgrade". That means some other package also needs to be updated. Don't know which one though.

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question, instead post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will stay as unsolved in the system forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could verify the fix after I did "apt upgrade". That means some other package also needs to be updated. Don't know which one though. It would be helpful if we can know which packages exactly need to be updated.